# Why do these two queries with 'EXISTS' behave differently?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, exists

There are two tables. `Customers` with `custid` as PK and `Orders` with `custid` as FK.

`Customers` table has columns `custid`, `companyname`

`Orders` table has columns `custid`, `orderid`, `orderdate`

I want to return the customers who ordered in 2007 and not in '2008'. I want to return `custid` and `companyname` in the final result.

I have query1 that fetches the right result with 7 distinct `custid` in total
I have query2 that gives me way more distinct rows, i.e 86 rows in the final result

query1

```sql
SELECT custid, companyname
FROM customers c
WHER EXISTS
 (SELECT custid
  FROM orders o
  WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = '2007'AND o.custid = c.custid)
AND NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT custid
  FROM orders o
  WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = '2008'AND o.custid=c.custid)
```

query2

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT custid, companyname
FROM customers c
WHERE EXISTS
 (SELECT custid
  FROM orders o
  WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = '2007'
        AND YEAR(orderdate) <> '2008'
        AND o.custid=c.custid)
```

I do not understand the problem with query2 and why it isn't able to give the correct results?

Comment: Could you please give us some sample data from both tables to work with?

Comment: The subquery in code2 will effectively query for all customers in 2007. Remember that the condition is evaluated per row: If the first condition (`= 2017`) holds, the second one (`<> 2018`) holds by definition.

Comment: When you say `YEAR(orderdate) = '2007'`, it can never be anything else (the conditionas are ***per row***) unless you introduce an `OR` condition. The specific value can't be 2007 and something else at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let us have the `customers` table with one customer (customer 1) and the following `orders` table

```
custid   orderid  orderdate
---------------------------
  1         1       1.1.2007
  1         2       1.1.2008
```

Your second query interpret the subquery for the customer

```
SELECT custid
FROM orders o
WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = 2007 AND YEAR(orderdate) <> 2008 AND o.custid = 1
```

and it returns the first row. Therefore, the `exists` is evaluated to `true` for the customer, because there is a row with `year(orderdate) = 2007 and year(orderdate) <> 2008` (the first row). HOWEVER, it does not mean that there does not exists different row with year 2008!

Clearly, the first query returns no result, because the customer 1 does not satisfy the `not exists` predicate. If we express the first query in the relational algebra then it corresponds to a difference between two sets, however, the second query is just a plain join with a condition.

Answer (score 2):

The correct query is **the first one**.

As user2722968 noted, using:
`WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = '2007' AND YEAR(orderdate) <> '2008'`
works per-row. So, if a custid has both an orderid in 2007 and another in 2008,
the aforementioned `WHERE` will indeed return the 2007 row, as it has indeed `YEAR(orderdate) = '2007' AND YEAR(orderdate) <> '2008'`.

On the contrary, the different codes in `(NOT) EXISTS` perform an operation (semijoi) not on rows, but on result-sets. This is what you need.

A suggestion: It is a good performance practice to not use functions if you can avoid them, because when you apply functions to a field, if there is an index on it, it cannot be used to speed up calcultations. Thus, instead of YEAR(orderdate)=2007, better use:

`orderdate>='20070101' and orderdate<'20080101'`

Considering this, the query becomes:

```
SELECT custid, companyname
FROM customers c
WHERE EXISTS
 (SELECT custid
  FROM orders o
  WHERE orderdate>='20070101' and orderdate<'20080101' AND o.custid = c.custid)
AND NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT custid
  FROM orders o
  WHERE orderdate>='20080101' and orderdate<'20090101' AND o.custid=c.custid)
```

Comment: Good performance tip. This is called [sargability](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable).

Answer (score 1):

> Why do these two queries with 'EXISTS' behave differently?

Because:

- The first query will return a customer if has an order in 2007 and doesn't have a (different) order in 2008.
- But the second query will return a customer if it has an order in 2007 but the same order is not in 2008 (and since the order is already in 2007, then it is not in 2008, so the condition `<> 2008` is redundant).

Looks like the first query makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is one easier way to solve this question with `EXCEPT`

```
select c.custid, c.companyname
from Customers c
join
Orders o
on o.custid=c.custid
where orderdate>='20070101' and orderdate<'20080101'
except
select c.custid, c.companyname
from [TSQL2012].Sales.Customers c
join
[TSQL2012].Sales.Orders o
on o.custid=c.custid
where orderdate>='20080101' and orderdate<'20090101'
```